# voice output smartphones(JS)

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis

So,I have already a code for voice output :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World');
window.speechSynthesis.speak(msg);

</script>
```

But on my smartphone that dont work!(I already tryed with a webside link and as HTML data on phone.)

Thx for every answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=SpeechSynthesisUtterance) `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` isn't supported everywhere and you are apparently using a browser on your phone that doesn't support it.